# I posted a question to the wrong intended SE site. Do we close questions as opposed to moving them?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, off-topic

Generally, I leave a closed question be and move on.  But yesterday, I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11415687/can-a-single-core-go-bad) that was clearly off-topic for SO.  I meant the question for SU, (I admit the question was somewhat marginal but was answerable) but mistakenly asked SO only because I was going back and forth between sites and happend to be SO.

Once I realized that I asked my question on the wrong site, I took steps to try and get it resolved.  I admited my mistake on a comment and I flagged the question as off-topic to move to SU for a moderator to move.  I checked the question again and found it closed this morning with another downvote.  **What should have I done when I realized I asked the question on the wrong site?**  I supposed I could have flagged it for deletion and reasked on SU, but I thought flagging it to be moved woulb a better option.  Thoughts anyone?

Comment: Downvote?  I was just curious as to why the mods chose to close the question half a day after I flagged it to be moved.  In the future, if this happens, I will surely be deleting the qeustion and reposting.

Comment: The mods didn't close your question; five regular community members did. Stack Overflow users _can_ vote to migrate to Super User, but the migration won't go through unless at least four out of the five close voters agree on the destination. It's possible that some of the close voters did not think your question was of high enough quality to deserve migration.

Comment: @PopularDemand That makes sense now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

[You can self delete the question immediately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/168428) as long as there are <= 1 answers, and that 1 answer (if it exists) has not been upvoted.  That's what I would have done.  Accidents happen.

Then you can just repost* the question on the proper site - no fallout (downvotes / closure), no confusion, no need to involve a moderator.  Everyone wins.

**Note: Reposting the same question to multiple sites is generally frowned upon.  But in a case like this (mistakenly posting, then self-deleting), I think it's fine.*

Answer (score 1):

Flag for a moderator to migrate.

Super User is on the list of migration targets for those with the right to vote to close (3,000+ reputation), but there's no reason to wait for 5 users to come across the question and vote to migrate.

Comment: Did I not flag it?

Comment: @hydroparadise - I don't know, I'm not a Stack Overflow moderator.

Comment: Although, to be honest, you are more likely to get the five users to get to the question before a moderator does =)